# insert/update/delete operation with merge operation oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a temp table and another one is master table. Everyday our interface runs and upload data in TEMP table.

Now bases on that, we have to update master table in 
1. If primary key(we have marked few column as primary key), then perform the update operation.
2. If primary key does not match, then perform the insert operation.

and if suppose we have 10 entry in TMP table and 12 entry in master, then perform the delete on those 2 entry from master table.

I am trying this with merge operation but insert and update is working. I am not sure how we can have delete operation performed in that

Comment: From your description I don't think you can do it with a single statement, but to clarify, please add some sample data, your current statement, current result and what you want the final data to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code. Hope this wil work for you.

```
DELETE FROM MASTER WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMP)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... Its working for me now. Now since I am enbadding my query in procedure, I am getting below error 

      Error(8,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar 



In my merge operation, I am doing insert/update for date fields also.. can you pls tell me how I can fix this

Comment: Can you plz share your proc here. so that i got a clear view of your problem.